# Why does my while loop end before the final message is printed? Is it my code or...?

Tags: python, while-loop

I made a guessing game where the player has 10 HP and has to randomly guess a number between 1 and 3 for multiple rounds until they've guessed correctly a total of 3 times.

I coped my code into a notepad file and saved it as 123game.py, then right-clicked and ran it using Python 3.8. When I did this, an odd thing happened.

I wanted a win message to say "It's over! Thank you for playing." But when the player guesses right for the 3rd time, Python just shuts down.

However I did not have the problem when I simply copy/pasted my code into Python. Is it my code that's wrong? Or should I not save a notepad file as .py and tell windows to open it by default with Python 3.8? I didn't have the problem with Pycharm.

```
import random
HP = 10
finish = 3
correct = [0]

while finish >= 0:
    value = random.randint(1, 3)
    correct.append(value)
    print("\nTry guessing a number 1, 2, or 3:")
    answer = int(input())
    if finish == 0:
        print("It's over! Thank you for playing.")
        break
    if HP == 0:
        print("You lose! Sorry.")
        break
    if answer > 3 or answer < 1:
        print("Out of bounds")
        continue
    if answer == value:
        print("correct")
        print(f"The answer was {correct[-1]}.")
        print(f"HP left: {HP}")
        finish -= 1
        print(f"correct answers until finish: {finish}")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        print(f"The answer was {correct[-1]}.")
        HP -= 1
        print(f"HP left: {HP}")
        print(f"correct answers until finish: {finish}")
        continue
```

Comment: When you "run" a file, it doesn't leave an open interpreter once it has executed all code. So it does really print out the last line, but immediately afterwards it quits the program because it has finished executing all code.

Comment: Add `input()` at the end of the script

Comment: @Taylor: What's your OS? (Unix-like or MS Window). If you're on a Unix-like platfom i.e *any Linux distros or Mac OSX*, then consider adding a **shebang** in the first line. Your shebang could be something like **#!/usr/bin/env python**

Comment: @eapetcho I'm using Windows 10

Comment: @faressalem: This solved the problem! But why?

Comment: @Taylor I’ve added an answer that might help other people.

Comment: @eapetcho Is there a workaround like this for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `input()` at the end of the script. It waits for any type of input from the user but without prompting him/her like `input(”Enter something: ”)` for example. Then the program ends (the same way it ended before, because there’s nothing else to execute) after pressing Return/Enter (so just press enter to exit the program). it’s naive, better consider the comments.

```
input() # or input(”Press Enter to exit”)`
```